# How to download photos from iCloud (iPhone 4)

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, data-transfer

I have an old iPhone 4 that I'm about to ditch. It has a couple of hundred photos on it, and I briefly looked into a way to access them directly from my Xubuntu laptop. (I no longer have Windows or Mac machines.) However, I decided against that route and decided to open an iCloud account, back-up the photos, and download them from iCloud through my browser. No problem, right?

Except that there *does* seem to be a problem. In iCloud.com it states that my iDevice need to be running iOS 8.x (don't remember the exact sub-version), and my phone is running 7.x, so I guess that's why the photos don't show. So I thought I could get them from the iCloud Drive and download them en masse without the benefits of pretty thumbnails, but there's nothing there either, despite the fact that apparently about 800 MB was uploaded from my phone.

**I'm looking for suggestions on how I can get these photos off this ancient iPhone, or out of iCloud if they're in there somewhere.** Thanks.

Comment: See the edited answer @craigH

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I don't know what iOS 7 looks like but you can try sharing the iCloud link with yourself as they are already backed up in the iCloud.
[image: Icloud link]

**2.** Other option can be to save all the photos to iCloud Drive(this is different from the photos thing) (if it is there). [image: Drive]

**3.** One can save them to notes and then wait for it to sync and then download it.

**4.** See if google photos or drive or Microsoft drive etc can store them.

**5.**  Firefox send is a good feature and is private too! If the above option makes you think that this is an app, you're wrong, it is a web tool. Go to [send.firefox.com](https://send.firefox.com)

**6.** This is a new thing I came across recently. Go to [Privacy-apple](https://privacy.apple.com) and download all the data. It might take a few in preparing the folder.

I did not remove the options that won't work for you for future readers.

Cheers!

Comment: I could have sworn I added a comment here before, but it's gone. I'll see if I can give my feedback in the limited space of a comment: 1 & 2: These options don't seem to be present on iOS 7 on my iPhone 4. 3: Don't see a way to add an image to a note. 4: Can't install modern apps. (This is what I recall my missing comment saying, about FF.) 5: Loading the page in Safari doesn't give me the option to upload files like it does on my laptop. 6: I am challenged with security questions I never set. In short, there doesn't seem to be away to get *my* photos out of Apple. Not impressed with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for trying. As you say, hopefully this will be useful to someone in the future.